# jq condensing sub array permutation query

Tags: arrays, query-optimization, export-to-csv, jq

I intend to extract a csv with a row for each sub array item. 
Given a json array with a sub array. e.g. like this one:

```
[
  {
     "foo": 108, 
     "bar": ["a","b"]
  },
  {   
     "foo": 201, 
     "bar": ["c","d"]
  }
]
```

It is possible to fetch the data by utilizing an intermediate object.

```
.[] | { "y": .foo,  "x": .bar[] }| [.y,.x]  | @csv
```

https://jqplay.org/s/922RlkbFNA

But I'd like to express it in a less elaborate form. 
However the following does not work :( :

```
.[] | [ (.foo,  .bar[]) ]  | @csv
```

*PS: I struggle to find a fitting headline*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In three lines:

```
.[]
| [.foo] + (.bar[]|[.])
| @csv
```

or maybe less obscurely:

```
.[]
| .bar[] as $bar
| [.foo, $bar] 
| @csv
```

Comment: thanks I didn't know the + operator could do that. I
was completely oblivious to the other usage of it https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Builtinoperatorsandfunctions